# lighttpd: How to forward port (visible only to localhost) to WAN after authentication?

Tags: apache, authentication, port, lighttpd

I have a webcam stream only accessible on the host machine via `http://localhost:1234`

This stream has no authentication.

I would like to setup a lightweight http server that listens on port 80 for outside connections, prompts for username and password, and then forwards the stream from `localhost:1234`

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lighttpd can do this.
The following config files will forward requests to http://domain.com/ => http://localhost:1234/ requesting a http basic auth first.

lighttpd.conf

```
## Add auth and proxy mods to your existing modules list
server.modules = (
    "mod_auth",
    "mod_proxy"
)


$HTTP["host"] == "domain.com" {

    auth.backend                = "plain"
    auth.backend.plain.userfile = "lighttpd-plain.user" 

    auth.require = (
        "/" => (
            "method"  => "basic",
            "realm"   => "MyWebcam",
            "require" => "valid-user" 
        )
    )

    proxy.server = (
        "/" => (
            (
                "host" => "127.0.0.1",
                "port" => 1234
            )   
        )
    )

}
```

lighttpd-plain.user

```
webcamuser:webcampassword
```

Make sure you load `mod_auth` before `mod_proxy` in `server.modules`, getting them in the wrong order can make lighty panic.

Comment: just one small caveat - the lighttpd-plain.user file must have absolute path (at least for me it did)

Comment: also, one final question - how do I add a path to the proxy? My webcam  is at `127.0.0.1:1234/webcam`. Is there a `"path" => "/webcam"` variable I can set?

Comment: Yes you should be able to change `"/" => (` to `"/webcam" => (`

Comment: I did try that, but it only matches the external incoming url with `/webcam` and redirects the internal to :1234 without the path

Comment: Sorry I thought it translated the full URL. I _THINK_, You should be able to forward the url with a rewrite. `url.rewrite-once = ( "^/webcam/(.*)$" => "/$1" )` but i've not tested that, so i cannot confirm :(